# ReferenceError: event is not defined on keyup event in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this code not work in Firefox? I want to make the switch pictures in gallery on keyup event. I had read similar problems and answers, but no one help me. jQuery 1.4.4
My code:

```
  $('body').live('keyup',function(e){

    if(e.keyCode  == 37) {
      $('.daPrev').click()
    }

    else if(e.keyCode  == 39) {
      $('.daNext').click()
    }

  })
```

When i press, in console:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

Comment: i dont know in which version `live` is removed... but try `on`

Comment: Dunno. Your code (when substituted for `on` which is the new `live` in the more recent versions of jQuery) works fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/c7q2c0oL/

Comment: @Mephiztopheles, the OP is on 1.4.4.

Comment: Yes, i tried, but $(...).on is not a function

Comment: OP? im sorry ... i dont know what this is...  `.delegate` is used in jquery 1.4.3+

Comment: No, but it should work for `live` in your example because you're using an old version of jQuery. JSFiddle will only allow me to go to 1.6.4 or something so I can't test your code properly.

Comment: OP = original poster.

Comment: ah ok... i saw .. `$('body').live`... did you try `$(document).live`?  here you can see the doc of `live` .. they say users of old versions should use `delegete` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: What is exact error message you have in console? I don't see any `event` variable in your posted code and FF is known for not setting it by default inside handler

Comment: Error seems not related to posted code, you should post handlers of events (click) you are trying to trigger. BTW, you should provide minimalistic code to replicate your issue, code snippet or jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any variable called event in your code, and it looks valid. However, some things you can try:

- Use .delegate
- Try a newer version of jQuery and switch to .on

.delegate:

```
$.delegate(selector, eventType, handler);
```

I.e.

```
$.delegate("div", "keyup", function(e) {...});
```

Comment: In console: $.delegate is not a function. 
On which version I can go that would not have to break? Because I don't do this site, and don't know what scripts and methods it use

Answer (score 0):

your code does not seem to caus the reference error. check other functions triggered, when you press.

i made a fiddle, tried in FF and console will log "37"

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmg34jfj/1/)

```
$('body').live('keyup',function(e){

  console.log('37')
    if(e.keyCode  == 37) {
      $('.daPrev').click()
    }

    else if(e.keyCode  == 39) {
       $('.daNext').click()
    }

})
```

Comment: Thank's, it because you use newest jQuery library. I have 1.4.4. I can't switch it, because i did not do site, and don't know what functions and method it use.

Comment: no. im not :) please check "External Resources" ;) jQuery-1.4.4.min.js

Comment: ah ok... i dont know what could caus this problem with this solvation.. but ... it works.. then its fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved using **jQuery migrate**. Thank's you all